# classNotFoundException GWTBridge

Tags: java, gwt, classnotfoundexception

im working on a gwt webapp

and while working on it im getting this exception while trying to get a XML file from a URL in a remove servlete.

i dont know much about the underworkings of gwt, maybe someone can help me out

this is the code to get the data from the url

```
public static String readURL(String path) throws IOException{
    String data = "";

    URL url = new URL(path);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));

    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        data += line;
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println(data.length());

    return data;
}
```

and this is the error im getting

```
        SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
    com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.cpsc310.sc2.client.RouteService.storeParsedData()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.xml.client.impl.XMLParserImpl.<clinit>(XMLParserImpl.java:29)
    at com.google.gwt.xml.client.XMLParser.<clinit>(XMLParser.java:28)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.cpsc310.sc2.server.parser.BikeRouteParser.parseRoutesbyDOM(BikeRouteParser.java:39)
    at com.cpsc310.sc2.server.RouteServiceImpl.storeParsedData(RouteServiceImpl.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.client.GWTBridge
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Is your code running on the server side or the client side?

Comment: that code that i pasted should be called on the server side

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you cannot use a class that's in a `client` package outside of a GWT client context (i.e. server-side)
(this is a rule we're trying to apply globally across `gwt-user.jar`, there are a few exceptions but they're mostly implementation details)

If you want to parse XML on your server, use `javax.xml`, not `com.google.gwt.xml.client`.

Comment: I thought the way to do it is to set up a service, and then the interface of the service will be in client, while the implementation is in server. at least thats how they did it in the tutorials

Comment: An interface is different, it doesn't contain _code_. BTW, many people now put their RPC interfaces in a `shared` package.

Comment: I found that I can instantiate a GWT class inside a method of a shared entity, but cannot place it as a member of the class. As long as you call it from the client side it works fine.

Comment: It'll actually depend on the JVM you use. OpenJDK and Sun/Oracle JVMs work, but I've heard others will fail early (trying to resolve native deps at class load time, rather than method call time)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below  in your project (make sure the package is right):

```
package com.google.gwt.core.client;
import com.google.gwt.core.shared.*;
/**
* Date: 1/17/13
* Time: 12:37 PM
* This class is used for fixing class not found com.google.gwt.core.client.GWTBridge;
*
* This is only needed for GXT 2 to work. Once we remove GXT2, this can be removed also.
*/
public abstract class GWTBridge extends com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWTBridge {
}
```

Original:
http://alexluca.com/2013/01/17/gwt-25-and-extgwt-224-classnotfoundexception-comgooglegwtcoreclientgwtbridge/