# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have included the following dependencies for GWT

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In spite of including GWT jars in the classpath, I am getting the below run time error.

```
2017.10.17 08:30:28 ERROR servlet(323): Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/GWTBridge
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Arrays$ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(Arrays.java:64)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Arrays$ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(Arrays.java:94)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Arrays$ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(Arrays.java:34)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:786)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:585)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:471)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:563)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
```

It seems like some issue exists in serializing/de-serializing array.
 Can you please help to resolve this error.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707020/gwt-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-gwt-core-client-gwtbridge

Comment: That class is part of the `gwt-dev` library, which is marked as _provided_. Are you sure the web server provides it?

Comment: Since gwt-dev dependency is required only at compile time, I have marked its scope as provided.I believe gwt-dev.jar should not be bundled in the WAR.

Comment: @Grai. This is a not a duplicate as in this case the error thrown is related to array serialization/de-serialization.

Comment: Try to upgrade to at least version 2.5.1, see https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7689 and https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/7527

Comment: @Berger. Thanks a ton. Upgrading gwt-servlet.jar version to 2.5.1 resolved this issue.

Comment: Nice, maybe your question will help other people :) !

Comment: Hopefully it helps others also. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this exception by upgrading gwt-servlet jar version from 2.5.0 to 2.5.1.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```